# Testing an Edit view with MVCContrib Test Helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-testhelper

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3, MVCContrib, NUnit and Rhino Mocks.  I have posted this but could not get an answer.  People are focusing more on my coding that helping me get a decent answer to get this test to pass.

I am trying to test my Edit view.  I'm not sure how to code the test for the view.  It is a strongly typed view of type NewsEditViewData.

When the view loads, it gets a news item's data by ID from the news service.  So in my test I created a stub of the news service:

```
var id = 1;
var news = new News();
newsServiceStub
   .Stub(x => x.FindById(id))
   .Return(news);
```

Now I need to map this news item to NewsEditViewData.  I have a mapper (AutoMapper) that does this for me, and in my test I did the following:

```
newsMapperStub
   .Stub(x => x.Map(news, typeof(News), typeof(NewsEditViewData)))
   .Return(newsEditViewData);
```

I'm not sure if I am on the right track so far?

Then I have the following piece of code:

```
// Act
var actual = sut.Edit(id);
```

Don't work from my code, I want an answer following best practices.  So what all do I need to check for in my assert part?  Do I need to also check that a record was returned?  I was thinking in the lines of something like:

```
actual
   .AssertViewRendered()
   .WithViewData<NewsEditViewData>()
   .ShouldBe(newsEditViewData);
```

This fails.  Can someone please help me rewrite this test so that it passes.  I want it to check all that needs to be checked.

Here is the full test:

```
[Test]
public void Edit_should_render_Edit_view()
{
   // Arrange
   var id = 1;
   var news = new News();
   var newsEditViewData = new NewsEditViewData();

   newsServiceStub
      .Stub(x => x.FindById(id))
      .Return(news);

   newsMapperStub
      .Stub(x => x.Map(news, typeof(News), typeof(NewsEditViewData)))
      .Return(newsEditViewData);

   // Act
   var actual = sut.Edit(id);

   // Assert
   actual
      .AssertViewRendered()
      .WithViewData<NewsEditViewData>()
      .ShouldBe(newsEditViewData);
}
```

**UPDATE 2011-02-14:**

In my NewsController I have the following:

```
private INewsService newsService;
private IMapper newsMapper;

public NewsController(INewsService newsService)
{
   Check.Argument.IsNotNull(newsService, "newsService");

   this.newsService = newsService;
   newsMapper = new NewsMapper();  // TODO: Use dependency injection
}
```

The action method looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
   Check.Argument.IsNotZeroOrNegative(id, "id");

   var news = newsService.FindById(id);
   var newsEditViewData = (NewsEditViewData)newsMapper.Map(news, typeof(News), typeof(NewsEditViewData));

   return View(newsEditViewData);
}
```

The error that I am getting in NUnit is:

**MyProject.Web.UnitTests.Controllers.NewsControllerTests.Edit_RenderView_EditView:
MvcContrib.TestHelper.AssertionException : was MyProject.Web.Common.ViewData.NewsEditViewData but expected MyProject.Web.Common.ViewData.NewsEditViewData**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown none of your controller, repository, models. It's a question that is close to impossible to answer without this information. So lets start guessing. You have a model and a view model:

```
public class News { }
public class NewsEditViewData { }
```

I am leaving them without any properties for the purpose of this post. Then you probably have a service which is responsible for retrieving and saving your model (the view model should never appear as in/out argument of your service layer). The service should never know about the view model:

```
public interface INewsService
{
    News FindById(int id);
    void CreateNews(News news);
}
```

Then you probably have a mapper:

```
public interface IMapper
{
    object Map(object source, Type sourceType, Type destinationType);
}
```

And finally I suppose that you have a controller that you are trying to test:

```
public class NewsController : Controller
{
    private readonly INewsService _newsService;
    private readonly IMapper _newsMapper;

    public NewsController(INewsService newsService, IMapper newsMapper)
    {
        _newsService = newsService;
        _newsMapper = newsMapper;
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        // WARNING: Meaningless action ahead as it retrieves some
        // model from the service and passes this model to
        // the service back again for update. In the meantime
        // the model is converted to a view model using a mapper
        // and passed to the view. So totally meaningless in a real 
        // application but let's consider for the purpose of this demonstration
        var news = _newsService.FindById(id);
        _newsService.CreateNews(news);
        var newsEditViewData = (NewsEditViewData)_newsMapper.Map(news, typeof(News), typeof(NewsEditViewData));
        return View(newsEditViewData);
    }
}
```

OK, up until here it is you that should have provided this information.

And now I can start answering your question about the unit test which might look like this:

```
[Test]
public void Edit_should_fetch_news_model_from_service_given_an_id_parameter_create_news_and_pass_a_viewmodel_to_the_view()
{
    // arrange
    // TODO : move this part in the initialization section 
    // of your unit test to avoid repeating it on each method
    var newsServiceStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<INewsService>();
    var newsMapperStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IMapper>();
    var sut = new NewsController(newsServiceStub, newsMapperStub);
    new TestControllerBuilder().InitializeController(sut);

    var news = new News();
    var id = 123;
    var newsEditViewData = new NewsEditViewData();
    newsServiceStub
        .Stub(x => x.FindById(id))
        .Return(news);

    newsMapperStub
        .Stub(x => x.Map(news, typeof(News), typeof(NewsEditViewData)))
        .Return(newsEditViewData);

    // act
    var actual = sut.Edit(id);

    // assert
    actual
        .AssertViewRendered()
        .WithViewData<NewsEditViewData>()
        .ShouldBe(newsEditViewData);
    newsServiceStub.AssertWasCalled(x => x.CreateNews(news));
}
```

Comment: Please see updated post.  Is there anything else that you need to see?  Our code looks the same, but the test still fails.

Comment: @Brendan Vogt, your code doesn't look as mine. In the constructor of your NewsController you have hardcoded the mapper: `newsMapper = new NewsMapper();` instead of using a real dependency injection and that's the reason your unit test fails.

Comment: I don't see the difference here harcoded or not? When the constructor of the NewsController is initiated then it creates the instance of the news mapper. With dependency injection you specify the instance to be provided.  Can you please explain?

Comment: @Brendan Vogt, your unit test fails because you are trying to define stubs on some `newsMapperStub` but this variable is never used/passed in your controller where you have hardcoded the real news mapper which makes your code untestable. So when the Map method is called inside the controller the real mapper returns some instance whereas in your unit test you have defined an expectation on this stub that it would return some predefined instance of the view model and you try to assert that the view was passed your predefined view model instance but that's not the case.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean.  Thanks.